# PHP - json not parsing through loop

Tags: php, json

Let's say my JSON is this:

```
{
  "achievement": [
    {
      "title": "All Around Submitter",
      "description": "Get one piece of content approved in all six areas.",
      "xp": 500,
      "level_req": 1
    },
    {
      "title": "World-wide Photo Journalist",
      "description": "Get one photo approved in all six areas.",
      "xp": 500,
      "level_req": 1
    },
    {
      "title": "Ready for Work",
      "description": "Sign up and get validated",
      "xp": 50,
      "level_req": 1
    },
    {
      "title": "Asian Pride",
      "description": "Get ten pieces of content approved to a club in an Asian nation.",
      "xp": 1500,
      "level_req": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

and my PHP code is this, so I load through that json file...:

```
<?php

$string = file_get_contents("achievements.json");
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);

foreach ($json_a as $key => $value){
  echo  $value[0]['title'] . " <br />";
}

?>
```

However it only out puts the first array. I know. Only 1. But what about the `foreach` loop?  Why isn't it loop for each row?

Comment: The outer associative array has only one item: *achievement*. That’s why there is only one iteration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looping over the top level array, which only has one key: `achievement`

Instead, you should

```
foreach ($json_a['achievement'] as $key => $value){
  echo  $value['title'] . " <br />";
}
```

Hint: `[0]` is a certain code smell.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. Top-level array, it was.

Answer (score 1):

Here try this

```
$string = file_get_contents("achievements.json");
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);

foreach ($json_a['achievement'] as $key => $value){
  echo  $value['title'] . " <br />";
}
```

Your were looping your top array, but after you parse your json you get:

```
array(1) {
  ["achievement"]=>
  array(4) {
  //your other arrays
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working because the array you are looping through only has one key, `achievements`, this is the array returned by your `json_decode()`, given your current json.  Loop through that, and you'll get what you're after:

```
foreach ($json_a['achievement'] as $key => $value){
    echo $value['title'] . "<br />";
}
```